# How to keep defaults yet make customization?

Tags: default-settings

I have no vi customizations at all and really like the default behavior where on a search using  /  the cursor immediately jumps to the match without having to hit enter

Problem is once I create file  ~/.vimrc and add anything like

```
set ts=4
set ic
```

the desired default behavior mentioned above goes away.  How to keep the system defaults yet make the slightest customization ?

> version 8.1.2269

```
$ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 18 2020 06:30:35)
Included patches: 1-2269
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      +sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-3deAkt/vim-8.1.2269=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lcanberra -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lm
```

I am on linux ubuntu

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  yes it does answer this question,  however I did not see it while googling about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these two lines to the top of your newly created `.vimrc`:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

For details, see [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim):

> If Vim is started normally and no user vimrc file is found, the `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` script is loaded.  This will set `'compatible'` off, switch on syntax highlighting and a few more things.  See the script for
>   details.
>
> **NOTE:** this is done since Vim 8.0, not in Vim 7.4. (it was added in patch 7.4.2111 to be exact).
>
> This should work well for new Vim users.  If you create your own `.vimrc`, it is recommended to add these lines somewhere near the top:
>
> ```
> unlet! skip_defaults_vim
> source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
> ```
>
> Then Vim works like before you had a `.vimrc`.

You might want to take a look inside the [`defaults.vim` file](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/defaults.vim) shipped with Vim, the comments in the file might be helpful as well.